# Total pages not working with jsPDF and jsPDF-autotable

Tags: javascript, node.js, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

There's a few questions out there that are related, but I seem to be following everything properly as far as I can see. Am I missing something here?

Basically, I'm using jsPDF and jsPDF-autotable to generate an invoice with multiple lines. The code works, just that I continue to get "Page 1 of {total_pages_count_string}" instead of the actual count. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Wrong data showing for total pages.]

Here's a snippet of what I'm attempting to do:

```
module.exports = function pdfDownload(jsPDF, print, invoiceData, fs, nodemailer) {

    var doc = new jsPDF({
        format: 'letter',
        orientation: 'p'
    });
    var systemVars = invoiceData.SystemVars;
    var invoiceData = invoiceData.OrderDetails;
    var totalPagesExp = "{total_pages_count_string}";

    // Full page table
    doc.autoTable({
        didDrawPage: function (data) {
            var pageCount = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages()
            // Total page number plugin only available in jspdf v1.0+
            if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
                pageCount = "Page " + pageCount + " of " + totalPagesExp;
            }

            // Header
            doc.setFontSize(10);
            doc.setTextColor(40);
            doc.setFont('helvetica');
            doc.text(invoiceLocationName + "\n" + invoiceLocationAddr1 + "\n" + invoiceLocationAddr2 + "\n" + invoiceLocationCSZ, data.settings.margin.left, 15);
            doc.text("Phone: " + invoiceLocationPhone, data.settings.margin.left + 187, 15, {
                align: 'right',
                valign: 'right'
            });
            if (base64Img) {
                doc.addImage(base64Img, 'PNG', data.settings.margin.left + 65, 10, 50, 18);
            }
            doc.autoTable({
                styles: {
                    lineWidth: 0.2,
                    lineColor: 0,
                    fontSize: 8,
                    overflow: 'ellipsize',
                    fillColor: false
                },
                alternateRowStyles: {
                    fillColor: false
                },
                bodyStyles: {
                    fillColor: false,
                    textColor: 0,
                },
                startY: 30,
                columnStyles: {
                    0: {
                        cellWidth: 32
                    },
                    1: {
                        cellWidth: 32
                    },
                    2: {
                        cellWidth: 32
                    },
                    3: {
                        cellWidth: 32
                    },
                    4: {
                        cellWidth: 29.68
                    },
                    5: {
                        cellWidth: 30
                    }
                },
                body: [
                    [{
                        content: 'Sold To',
                        colSpan: 2,
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: 'Ship To',
                        colSpan: 2,
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: 'PO Date',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'right',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceOrderDate
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: invoiceSoldTo1 + '\n' + invoiceSoldTo2 + '\n' + invoiceSoldTo3 + '\n' + invoiceSoldTo4 + '\n' + invoiceSoldTo5,
                        colSpan: 2,
                        rowSpan: 4
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceShipTo1 + '\n' + invoiceShipTo2 + '\n' + invoiceShipTo3 + '\n' + invoiceShipTo4 + '\n' + invoiceShipTo5,
                        colSpan: 2,
                        rowSpan: 4
                    }, {
                        content: 'Invoice Number',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'right',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceInvoiceNo
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: 'Order Number',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'right',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceOrderNo
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: 'Invoice Date',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'right',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceInvoiceDate
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: 'Invoice Type',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'right',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceInvoiceType
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: 'Customer PO',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: 'Ship VIA',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: 'Terms',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: 'Writer',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: 'Trans Code',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: 'Acct#',
                        styles: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            halign: 'center',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: invoiceCustOrderNo
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceShipVia
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceTerms
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceWriter
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceTransCode
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceAccountNo
                    }],
                ],
            });

            // Footer page numbers
            doc.setFontSize(10);

            // jsPDF 1.4+ uses getWidth, <1.4 uses .width
            var pageSize = doc.internal.pageSize;
            var pageHeight = pageSize.height ? pageSize.height : pageSize.getHeight();
            doc.text(pageCount, data.settings.margin.left, pageHeight - 10);

            // Left and Right Line
            doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
            doc.setLineWidth(0.2);
            doc.line(14.1, 80, 14.1, 250);
            doc.line(201.789, 80, 201.789, 250);

            // Footer fine print
            doc.autoTable({
                styles: {
                    lineWidth: 0.2,
                    lineColor: 0,
                    fontSize: 6.5,
                    fillColor: false,
                    cellPadding: 0.8
                },
                alternateRowStyles: {
                    fillColor: false
                },
                bodyStyles: {
                    fillColor: false,
                    textColor: 0,
                },
                startY: pageHeight - 66.6,
                body: [
                    [{
                        content: "Information Here.",
                        colSpan: 3
                    }],
                ]
            });

            // Footer details
            doc.autoTable({
                styles: {
                    lineWidth: 0.2,
                    lineColor: 0,
                    fontSize: 8,
                    fillColor: false
                },
                alternateRowStyles: {
                    fillColor: false
                },
                bodyStyles: {
                    fillColor: false,
                    textColor: 0,
                },
                startY: pageHeight - 57,
                columnStyles: {
                    0: {
                        cellWidth: 130
                    },
                    1: {
                        cellWidth: 35
                    },
                    2: {
                        cellWidth: 22.68
                    },
                },
                body: [
                    [{
                        content: invoiceNote1 + "\n" + invoiceNote2 + "\n" + invoiceNote3 + "\n" + invoiceNote4 + "\n\n",
                        rowSpan: 4
                    },
                    {
                        content: ""
                    },
                    {
                        content: ""
                    }
                    ],
                    [{
                        content: ""
                    }, {
                        content: ""
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: ""
                    }, {
                        content: ""
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: "Freight:",
                        styles: {
                            halign: 'right',
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceFreight,
                        styles: {
                            halign: 'right'
                        }
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: "Signature __________________________________________________________________",
                        rowSpan: 2,
                        styles: {
                            valign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: "Tax:",
                        styles: {
                            halign: 'right',
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceSalesTax,
                        styles: {
                            halign: 'right'
                        }
                    }],
                    [{
                        content: "Pay this Amount:",
                        styles: {
                            halign: 'right',
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                        }
                    }, {
                        content: invoiceTotal,
                        styles: {
                            halign: 'right'
                        }
                    }]
                ]
            });

        },
        styles: {
            lineWidth: 0.2,
            lineColor: 0,
            fontSize: 8,
            showHead: 'everyPage',
            overflow: 'ellipsize'
        },
        headStyles: {
            fillColor: false,
            textColor: 0
        },
        margin: {
            top: 77.4,
            bottom: 62
        },
        head: [
            [{
                dataKey: 'seq',
                content: 'Seq.',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'ord',
                content: 'Ord',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'shp',
                content: 'Shp',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'boq',
                content: 'BO',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'line',
                content: 'Line',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'partnumber',
                content: 'Part Number',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'description',
                content: 'Description',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'um',
                content: 'UM',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'list',
                content: 'List',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'cost',
                content: 'Cost',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            },
            {
                dataKey: 'extcost',
                content: 'Ext. Cost',
                styles: {
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    halign: 'center',
                    fillColor: [220, 220, 220]
                }
            }
            ]
        ],
        body: bodyRows(invoiceData)
    });

    function bodyRows(invoiceData) {
        let body = [];
        var pdfOrderDetails = invoiceData.OrderLines.OrderLine;
        pdfOrderDetails.forEach(obj => {
            body.push({
                0: obj.LineNo,
                1: obj.QtyOrd,
                2: obj.QtyShip,
                3: obj.QtyBO,
                4: obj.LineCode,
                5: obj.PartNo,
                6: obj.Description,
                7: obj.UOM,
                8: {
                    content: "-",
                    styles: {
                        halign: 'right'
                    }
                },
                9: {
                    content: obj.EachPrice,
                    styles: {
                        halign: 'right'
                    }
                },
                10: {
                    content: obj.ExtPrice,
                    styles: {
                        halign: 'right'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        return body;
    }

    // Total page number plugin only available in jspdf v1.0+
    if (typeof doc.putTotalPages === 'function') {
        doc.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp);
    }

    var fullPathOut = './data/out/' + invoiceOrderNo + '.pdf';
    doc.save(fullPathOut);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Typescript/Angular you may try this. hope this helps.

```js
    // Footer i.e Page 1 of 4 
    // Get the number of pages
    const pageCount = (doc as any).internal.getNumberOfPages(); //was doc.internal.getNumberOfPages(); 
    // For each page, print the page number and the total pages
    for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
      doc.setFontSize(10);
      // Go to page i
      doc.setPage(i);
      var pageSize = doc.internal.pageSize;
      var pageHeight = pageSize.height ? pageSize.height : pageSize.getHeight();
      doc.text('Page ' + String(i) + ' of ' + String(pageCount), doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 2, pageHeight - 8); //data.settings.margin.left if you want it on the left
    }
```